# jQuery "$(document).ready(function () {" equivalent in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$(document).ready equivalent without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)

I want to wait until an ASP.NET `datagrid` is resized correctly before showing a popup message. This works great:

```
$(document).ready(function () { showpopup(); });
```

But I need to acheive it without jQuery. I've tried many ways:

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {showpopup();}

$(function() { showPopup();}
```

but this doesn't work.

Comment: `window.onload = function() {`

Comment: [$(document).ready equivalent without jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)

Comment: Why do both your non-jQuery ways involve calling a function called `$`?

Comment: onload and ready are **very** different

Answer (score 3):

My preferred method of doing such things is to start my script with:

```
var loadScripts = [],
    loadScript = function(callback) {loadScripts.push(callback);
```

Then, the very last thing on the page before `</body>` is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">(function() {var x; while(x=loadScripts.shift()) x();})();</script>
```

Then, whenever there's something I want to defer until the DOM has loaded, I simply enclose it in:

```
loadScript(function() {
    // do stuff here
});
```